# SQL error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou importando um sql com o seguinte código:

```
CREATE TABLE blog (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
body TEXT NOT NULL,
url VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL);
```

Mas está retornando o seguinte erro:

> Notice in ./import.php#704
>   Undefined variable: import_text
>   Backtrace

Comment: o erro não tem a ver com a sua query de sql..

Comment: O código SQL apresentado não possui nenhum erro. O erro exibido está relacionado ao seu código PHP.